# Can I change the message for System.Windows.Data Error: 7?

Tags: wpf, xaml

If I put a string inside a TextBox (in XAML) that expects an integer, I get the message:

> The value "xy" could not be converted.

Someone please tell me if I may introduce a custom error message like the following instead:

> Please enter a number.

Comment: May be this will help you: http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/06/24/wpf-textbox-validation.aspx

Comment: thx is exactly what i wanted

Comment: I moved it to answers then

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to override the default validation method of your TextBox's rule, which is the rule's ValidationResult Validate method, in the code behind the page and have this method return a ValidationResult consisting of your string, which is "Please enter a number."